# Replace header row for all csv files in a specific folder and create updated file in another folder?

Tags: batch, csv

I will be getting csv files regularly posted to a specific folder. Whenever the files are posted, I want my batch script to modify the header values and create a new file in a separate location (modified folder) with the same file name as original file, I still want the same data for the other rows, just different headers. I found a script online and was trying to edit it but I don't know enough about scripts to get it to work.

```
@SET "HEADERS=SITEID,SUBJECTID,RESULTSP,RESULTSN,RESULTSComments"
@FOR /F "DELIMS=," %%A IN ('C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Test *.csv') DO @((ECHO %HEADERS%
IN ('C:\Users\Documents\scripts\Test\Modified')"%%~A"))
```

Where exactly is this script going wrong?

I will be using Active Batch to schedule the script to run whenever a new file is posted into the folder.

Comment: I also found this script and I got it to work a little but it adds the header row above the already existing header instead of replacing it and it replaces the original file. I don't know how to modify it to create a separate file in a different location.  It uses a separate txt file to get the header row.      
        for 
        %%F in ("Documents\scripts\Test\*.csv") do (
        > "%%~F.csv" type "Header.txt"
        >> "%%~F.csv" type "%%~F"
        move /Y "%%~F.csv" "%%~F"
        )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it worked for me...

```
@echo off

:: Put the path to the original CSV files here:
set OldCSVPath=Original
:: Put the path to the new CSV files here:
set NewCSVPath=New

if not exist "%NewCSVPath%" md "%NewCSVPath%"

SET "HEADERS=SITEID,SUBJECTID,RESULTSP,RESULTSN,RESULTSComments"

for %%a in ("%OldCSVPath%\*.csv") do (
                                      >>"%NewCSVPath%\%%~nxa" echo %HEADERS%
                                      for /f "skip=1 Delims=" %%b in ('type "%%a"') do >>"%NewCSVPath%\%%~nxa" echo %%b
                                     )
exit
```

Here are my testings: [ChangeHeader.gif](https://i.imgur.com/Z4gypYl.gif)

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect!